# Can an SSRS Report in ReportViewer web part access the URL or site name of the site hosting it?

Tags: 2010, reporting-services

I have several sites with pages with ReportViewer web parts on those pages.
All web parts use a central report file (.rdl) in a report document library in a reports site.

I would like these reports to show different data based on which site they are being viewed on.

The sites are :

```
https://name.company.com/sites/reports
https://name.company.com/sites/site01
https://name.company.com/sites/site02
https://name.company.com/sites/site03
etc.
```

I would like to be able to have the report "know" that it is on site01, site02, site03, etc at run-time and be able use that information to query the appropriate data from SQL Server.

I have been able to store "site01" in a SharePoint list on site01 , "site02" in a SharePoint list on site02, etc, and pass that in as a Parameter to the web part and that works. But I am looking for way for the report itself to determine it's site/context without passing in information as a parameter through connected web parts.

I know SSRS reports can determine the user that is viewing the reports, I just can't seem to find a way to get the Site name/title/URL without passing it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Globals!ReportServerUrl` variable from within Report Builder:

[image]

If you just want the base URL of the site, then remove the `_vti_bin` bit by using an expression:

```
=Replace(Globals!ReportServerUrl,"/_vti_bin/ReportServer","")
```

Comment: Thanks. I verified it works and also that it works when the report file (.rdl) is stored in a document library on a central site and viewed via a ReportViewer web part on a different site.